# Validation failed for classes Semester during persist time

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I get the following error when I try to enter invalid value (value < 1 and > 19), but everything work okay if I try to enter a valid value (between 1 and 19)

```
Validation failed for classes [univ_orientation.dz.Entity.Semester] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must be greater than or equal to 1', propertyPath=Moyenne, rootBeanClass=class univ_orientation.dz.Entity.Semester, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Min.message}'}
]
```

`

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="Semester")
 public class Semester {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Column(name="idSemester")
private int idSemester;

@Column(name="SemesterNumber")
private int SemesterNumber;

@NotNull
@Min(1)
@Max(19)
@Column(name="Moyenne")
private double Moyenne;

@Column(name="Credit")
private int Credit;

@Column(name="Session")
private String Session;

@ManyToOne( cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="Student_idStudent")
private Student student;
```

// getters and setters

`my dao`

            @Override
            public void saveSemester(Semester semester) {

```
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(semester);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        saveSemester: "+e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

`

Comment: You have set up validation in the below code not to accept any values aout of 1-19 range. @NotNull
@Min(1)
@Max(19)
@Column(name="Moyenne")
private double Moyenne;

Comment: You have set validations for the column Moyenne. Hence you are getting the error